# Google Maps Android API v2: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException not thrown anymore

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

After updating Google Play Services to version 18, seems that GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException can't be used anymore. This piece of code:

```
try {
    MapsInitializer.initialize(ctx);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

generates this error:

> Unreachable catch block for GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException.
>   This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

How can I achieve the same result now? 
Thanks

Comment: it is not clear what "same result" you are talking about.Please elaborate

Comment: @kgandroid I want to preserve safe code, catching the exception.

Comment: ok...then you can just use catch(Exception e){e.printstacktrace()//or whatever you want to do within catch}

Comment: @kgandroid thanks but I know. The thing I wanted to understand is if I could use another piece of code, consistent with this last version of Google Play Services. Something similar to GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException.

Comment: you can use this:int checkGooglePlayServices =    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
    if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    // google play services is missing!!!!
    /* Returns status code indicating whether there was an error. 
    Can be one of following in ConnectionResult: SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID.
    */
       GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices, mActivity, 1122).show();
    }

Answer (score 5):

Now the function `initialize()` returns a `ConnectionResult` so you can do something like this:

```
if (MapsInitializer.initialize(ctx) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    // Handle the error
}
```